# pure functions in nested select

Tags: filtering

I want to select certain rows from a list by using two nested Select commands

```
Select[List1, #[[2]] >= 
   Select[List2, #[[1]] == IntegerPart[2* PREVIOUS#[[1]] ]/2 &] &]
```

where by PREVIOUS#[[1]] I mean the first argument of the previous pure function (i.e. the argument of the list List1). I  think this question may be duplicated, since I found that people solves this kind of problems using Function[], but I cannot figure out how (Sorry for my ignorance, I am new in Mathematica).

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Function` you can give the parameters a name:

```
Select[
  List1, 
  Function[a, a[[2]] >= Select[
    List2, 
    Function[b, b[[1]] == IntegerPart[2*a[[1]]]/2]
  ]]
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that, I was not sure whether using "Function[]"  and the "&" notation was exactly equivalent. And again, sorry for my stupid question!