# Arguments of Array function in prefix form

Tags: list-manipulation

How to make Array as in following example but without `list` variable as first argument, but **only** as last *postfix* argument ?

```
list = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
Array[list[[#]] &, Length[#]] &@list
```

Expected result:

```
{100, 200, 300, 400, 500}
```

**EDIT:** I'm expect 1st argument in the form `body &`, and not something like `Function[x, body]` or definition of new nonpure function.

Comment: I would just write  `list = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
f[n_] := list[[n]]; Array[f, Length@list]` and it is simpler also :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is basically a duplicate of [pure functions in nested select](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72196/45431). Applying the accepted answer to your question:

```
list = {100, 200, 300, 400, 500};
Array[Function[x, #[[x]]], Length[#]]& @ list
```

> {100, 200, 300, 400, 500}