# bind specific 'Slots' to specific 'Map'

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, map, pure-function, slot

Is it possible to construct a pure function using multiple slots, with the following concept :

Binding    ***specific slot***    to    ***specific apply*** or ***map***

For example :

[image]

In this example,

To reproduce the output for In(1), namely Out(1),

```
In[1] Table[Take[#, n], {n, 1, Length[#]}] & /@ test
Out[1] {{{4}, {4, 2}, {4, 2, 2}}, {{9}, {9, 1}, {9, 1, 5}}, 
       {{5}, {5, 2}, {5, 2, 9}, {5, 2, 9, 3}}, 
       {{5}, {5, 2}, {5, 2, 7}, {5, 2, 7, 1}, {5, 2, 7, 1, 1}}}
```

without using 'Table' symbol, I could do

```
In[2] Function[x, (Function[y, Take[x, y]] /@ Range[Length[x]])] /@ test
```

But I want to reproduce Out(1), only with slot symbols and Map.

The codes

```
((Take[#1, #2] &) /@ Range[Length[#1]]) & /@ test
```

or

```
((Take[#, #] &) /@ Range[Length[#]]) & /@ test
```

are tryable but they fails.

My imaginary working colored code is like :

[image]

Violet # binds to violet & and violet /@,
Green # binds to green & and green /@

Comment: What about: `Function[x, Take[x, #] & /@ Range[Length[x]]] /@ test`

Comment: Not using 'Function'.. Do you think it is possible ?

Comment: Try e.g.: `FoldList[Append, {First@#}, Rest@#] & /@ test`  or i f you are a fan of cryptic code: `(t = #; Take[t, #] & /@ Range[Length[#]]) & /@ test`

Comment: It's worth noting, by the way, that `&` with `#` is simply shorthand for `Function` with a parameter, so the `Function` solution is actually how you would bind a slot (in this case, named `x`) in an anonymous function properly.

Comment: You cannot bind a `Slot` to a `Function` constructor `&` outside another constructor `&` ("outside" being defined by syntactic precedence).  As far as I know, at least.  This came up before, but as I recall, it was not the central question, just the explanation of the problem with the OP's code.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that `Slot[]` binds to the first `Function` going up the expression tree to the head. To visualize your last example: `(Take[#1, #1] &) /@ Range[Length[#1]] & // TreeForm`  The first `Slot[1]` in `Take[..]` won't bind to the topmost `Function` as desired. You would need a way to label the slots and the function, but such a way is already provided by symbolic arguments.

Comment: This question comes up a lot but unfortunately there is no canonical one.  See also: [(38393)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/38393/142), [(16953)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16953/142), [(74140)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/74140/142),  [(79538)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/79358/142), [(72196)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72196/142), [(28983)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/28983/142), [(SO 4920194)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4920194).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct notation for anonymous slot references to outer pure function arguments (named arguments to `Function` having been ruled out).  But we can use the higher-order function [OperatorApplied](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OperatorApplied.html) as a way to avoid explicit argument naming:

```
OperatorApplied[Take, 2][#] /@ Range@Length[#] & /@ test

(* {{{4}, {4,2}, {4,2,2}},
    {{9}, {9,1}, {9,1,5}},
    {{5}, {5,2}, {5,2,9}, {5,2,9,3}},
    {{5}, {5,2}, {5,2,7}, {5,2,7,1}, {5,2,7,1,1}}} *)
```

or, equivalently:

```
OperatorApplied[Take[#2, #]&][#] /@ Range@Length[#] & /@ test
```

For this particular case, [CurryApplied](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurryApplied.html) could be substituted for `OperatorApplied`.  We could also use [Curry](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Curry.html) (my old favourite) but it has been deprecated and slated for removal some day.

See [(197168)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197168/142) for more discussion of this currying technique within nested pure functions.

---

**Just For Fun**

If Wolfram Language had some kind of forking operator, we could dispense with slot notation for this example and write in point-free form:

```
fork[f_][g_, h_][x_] = f[g[x], h[x]]

test // Map@fork[Map][Curry[Take,2], Range@*Length]

(* {{{4}, {4,2}, {4,2,2}},
    {{9}, {9,1}, {9,1,5}},
    {{5}, {5,2}, {5,2,9}, {5,2,9,3}},
    {{5}, {5,2}, {5,2,7}, {5,2,7,1}, {5,2,7,1,1}}} *)
```

The [Query](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html) sublanguage has something resembling a fork operator, so we can write:

```
test // Query[All, Apply[Map]@*{Curry[Take, 2], Range@*Length}]
```

Comment: I'm really going to miss `Curry`.  I dislike long names like `OperatorApplied` or `CurryApplied` for common (at least for me) operations.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it even without slots:

```
Map[Map[Flatten @* List] @* FoldList[List]] @ test
```

> ```
>  {{{4}, {4, 2}, {4, 2, 2}}, 
>   {{9}, {9, 1}, {9, 1, 5}}, 
>   {{5}, {5, 2}, {5,  2, 9}, {5, 2, 9, 3}}, 
>   {{5}, {5, 2}, {5, 2, 7}, {5, 2, 7, 1}, {5, 2, 7, 1, 1}}}
> ```

Also

```
Map[Extract[#, Map[List] @ Range @ Range @ Length @ #] &] @ test
```

> ```
>  {{{4}, {4, 2}, {4, 2, 2}}, 
>   {{9}, {9, 1}, {9, 1, 5}}, 
>   {{5}, {5, 2}, {5,  2, 9}, {5, 2, 9, 3}}, 
>   {{5}, {5, 2}, {5, 2, 7}, {5, 2, 7, 1}, {5, 2, 7, 1, 1}}}
> ```